# How do I merge two Pandas DataFrames and add the overlapping columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge multiple DataFrames on same DocID then sum up the weights but when I do merge it creates Weight_x,Weight_y. This would be fine for only two DataFrames but the amount of Dataframes to merge changes based on user input so merging creates Weight_x, Weight_y multiple times. So how can I merge more than 2 DataFrames such that they are merging on DocID and Weight is Summed?

Example:

```
df1= DocID Weight
     1     4
     2     7
     3     8
df2= DocID Weight
     1     5
     2     9
     8     1
finalDf=
     DocID Weight
     1     9
     2     16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge, set the 'DocID' column as the index, then sum the remaining columns together. Then you can reindex and rename the columns in the resulting final_df as needed:

```
df_final = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['DocID']).set_index(['DocID']).sum(axis=1)
df_final = pd.DataFrame({"DocID": df_final.index, "Weight":df_final}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_final
   DocID  Weight
0      1       9
1      2      16
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says 'Cannot merge a Series without a name'

Comment: Works! Thank you very much. I tried to upvote but my rep is low

Comment: No worries! If it was helpful, accepting the answer would be nice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.set_index('DocID').add(df2.set_index('DocID')).dropna()

        Weight
DocID   
1       9.0
2       16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['DocID']).set_index(['DocID']).sum(axis=1)`
You can now give any name to the sum column.